# Load UITableViewCell to UITableView in xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

OK I saw many forums and I did not find anything concrete with the problem that I have.

- **I have a ViewController where I added a UITableView.**

[image]

- **The UITableView loads a UITableViewCell created as xib file**

[image]

- **The TableViewCell has a UITableView that in turn has a UITableViewCell created also as a xib file.**

[image]

[image]

- This is how load the firts UITableViewCell inside the Firts UITableView. The load in ViewController:

  `tableDetails.delegate = self
          tableDetails.dataSource = self
          tableDetails.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DepartureDetailTableViewCell")`

> The problem is that I do not know how I'm going to load the Second UITableViewCell inside the Second UITableView in xib file from the ViewController. Any help?. And also, how do this for the Second UITableView/UITableViewCell.

[image]

**PD.:** See this tutorial, but he use prototype cell inside ViewController: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znGd5kyIdgM

Please Help!

**UPDATE:**

OK i solve the problem with @Abdelahad Darwish solution! but i have another problem...when load the DepartureInsideTableViewCell in DepartureDetailTableViewCell...not show anything... it show like this:

[image]

Has to show the DepartureInsideTableViewCell in the middle of the two view "May 30, 2018 - 01:04" and "May 30, 07:47"

Any help?

Comment: So you have `UIViewController` With `TableView`, and cell of `Main TableView` have another `TableView` with `CustomCell`

Comment: yes...that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First for Your `MainTableView`  Just Register Normal Cell from Xib
Just do it normal and  DepartureDetailTableViewCell will have all Datasource and delegate for Inside cell  Like that :

*don't forget to write correct cell identifiers and so on*

**In ViewController :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "DepartureDetailTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DepartureDetailsTableViewCell")
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DepartureDetailTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DepartureDetailTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4 // cell data source
    }
}
```

**In DepartureDetailTableViewCell:**

```
class DepartureDetailTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "DepartureInsideTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DepartureInsideTableViewCell")
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }


}

extension DepartureDetailTableViewCell: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DepartureInsideTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as!  DepartureInsideTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4 // cell data source
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't why but in extension DepartureDetailTableViewCell: say: "extension DepartureDetailTableViewCell:" help!

Comment: Yes what is your problem

Comment: Sorry.. this say: Use of undeclared type 'DepartureInsideTableViewCell'

Comment: yes Add you cell , what is your cell name `DepartureInsideTableViewCell` replace it with your own cell name

Comment: how this please share your code  i give you the idea you should make sure that you create correct cell and write its correct name

Comment: ok...i solved..! the problem was set the DepartureInsideTableViewCell delegate and dataSourse to the "File's Owner"... now i have another problem... i will update the question with a image. Thanks! i will appreciated the continues support!

Comment: Can you tell me what is the new problem? :)

Comment: Sorry I missed last message what is new problem you have